# What is the difference between IMO and IMHO and IHOP?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-difference, slang

I was reading a public forum, and I saw the following abbreviations:

- IMO
- IMHO
- IHOP

As far as I see, these are interchangeable somehow, but I don't understand the correct usage of them.
Just assuming the

> IMO

Probably stands for "In my Opinion",

and the extra 'H' letter stands for the Honest (or other references says: Humble).

I don't understand with the extra "H" does it sarcastic or even rude to say?

For the last one, I have absolutely no clue. I've tried to google it, and I ended up with:
[image]

--

After all, I don't know how to use these abbreviations.
Plus, is it common in the spoken language as a slang?

*Edited with an example of the last one*

> Person 1: Hey you wanna go out later tonight?
>
> Person 2: IHOP
>
> Person 1: Damn, maybe next time

I appreciate every answer!

Comment: The first two are correct, but I'm not sure I have ever seen IHOP used as an internet acronym. Do you have any examples of it being used in a sentence?

Comment: Yes, I have. I'm gonna edit the post above.

Comment: I have never seen IHOP used as an internet acronym except to mean "International House of Pancakes", in which case it has nothing to do with the first two.

Comment: I upvoted exclusively because IHOP made me laugh so much

Comment: Ah, but perhaps Person2 already had plans to eat at IHOP, or regularly eats there, and Person1 hates eating there, and Person2 is aware of this so they didn't need to say anything else afterward.

Comment: Or person 2 is saying they already went out and ate at IHOP and don't want to go out again.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

- IMO - in my opinion
- IMHO - in my honest/humble opinion

Both of these are very well known internet acronyms, and have been used for many years.

Both expressions are more or less interchangeable, and *in my humble opinion* is not by itself sarcastic - it should be taken as being genuine sign of humility, unless something else in the sentence indicates otherwise. Its sincerity depends entirely on context. For example:

> IMHO, I think that the MacBook pro is overpriced.
>
> IMHO, you're an idiot.

...are worlds apart in their sincerity.

Based on the context of the conversation you provided, I am guessing that **IHOP** stands for ***I*** **H**ave **O**ther **P**lans, and is not a commonly used acronym from what I can see.

[edit] Apparently the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?defid=4893803&term=IHOP) agrees with the meaning of IHOP, and oddly, uses the same example that the OP provided.

Comment: Ohh, I see! Never thought about that!
However, is there any difference between the first two acronyms?
Can be sarcastic or rude to use them?

Comment: To my ear there's no difference between the two. Neither is usually rude; they're typically earnest expressions of opinion which communicate understanding that others may disagree. Of course this can be eclipsed when the opinion expressed (e.g. "you're an idiot") is rude _pe se_.

Comment: Thank you, I was scared to may offend someone accidentally by using these abbreviations, but for now I get it!

Comment: Some points about their usage: __IMO__ and __IMHO__ are typically spelled out (i.e. "eye-em-oh"), while __IHOP__ is just pronounced "eye-hop".  Also, since __IMO__/__IMHO__ are _internet acronyms_, in formal written English and any spoken context, one would typically use the full phrase instead.

Comment: IMO "sarcastic" isn't quite the right word to describe IMHO, but I thought the basic meaning of IMHO was always "This is my opinion, and anybody who has a different opinion is just *wrong*".

Comment: Despite the strong tendency to discard the distinction, I for one consider the distinction between *abbreviation* and *acronym* valuable and suggest that, however things are drifting, we are at least *not yet* at the point where an answer on this site should mix the two. *IMO* and *IMHO* are not acronyms. No one reads them as a word, they read them as letters, *eye-em-oh* and *eye-em-aytch-oh*. On the other hand, *IHOP*, at least when referring to the diner, is an acronym, pronounced *eye-hop*. No idea about *IHOP* meaning *I have other plans* since I have never encountered that.

Comment: I think in the example used it still meant International House Of Pancakes, and Person 1 just really dislikes pancakes...

Comment: Historically, on newsgroups, `IMO` meant "I'm phrasing this as an opinion, but I'm pretty sure it's right", while `IMHO` meant "I'm not sure, here's what I think".

Comment: Hmm, I would read/say Im-ho almost always, and Eye-mo sometimes (rather than spelling them out). But of course your mileage may vary. Or, as I like to say, yuuhmuuhv. (Juhk on that last one. And this one.)

Comment: IMHO (in my humble opinion) dates back to a time when people were polite and deferential to fellow net users who could be as intelligent as the user. IMO gets rid of the connotation of humility arising from respect.

Comment: I've also seen IMNSHO. http://www.internetslang.com/IMNSHO-meaning-definition.asp

Comment: @Traktor53 : it was really used a lot on newsgroups before "the September that never ended" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September)

Comment: @verbose And IMNSHO highlights the fact that the H is usually "humble" not "honest", since it's used for "in my not so humble opinion".  Saying "in my not so honest opinion" is possible, but it's not likely, and feels awkward.

Comment: Even Urban dictionary lists "I Have Other Plans" as the 16th definition, not the first, and that entry has more downvotes than upvotes. "International house of pancakes" is definitely the far more common meaning, even amongst Urban Dictionary users.

Comment: But can the H really stand for "honest"? That would really change the meaning of "IMHO"... IMHO. :P

Comment: A good answer overall, but "IMHO, I think that the MacBook Pro is overpriced" is redundant. It should just be "IMHO, the MacBook Pro is overpriced."

Answer (score 7):

I Hate Old People

I Hate Other People

I.H.O.P.
a hard hit in football. referring to the common slang of pancake for the same meaning

IHOP
(International House of Prayer) IHOP

iHOP    Information Hyperlinked Over Proteins

IHOP    International House of Pain (slang for sports conditioning)

IHOP    Internal Heat or Pressure

IHOP    International Health Opportunities Program

You would have to know the context to understand the acronym.

Comment: I thought it has similar meaning like the first two abbreviations, but instead of that it has plenty of different meaning! Thank you for the list!

Comment: I just ask because I completely get all these things wrong. I often google them, and try to see if something fits.

Comment: Indeed, for every acronym one may find many fitting interpretations, depending on context (and on the reader's wit and amusement). And the same goes for words!

Comment: IHOP >> I Have Other Plans.    If you read the text exchange between the two people, it is pretty obvious what was meant.

Comment: @levteck That had already been in an answer, so I did not repeat it. Am I meant to? I try not to say what others have said first and perfectly well. I am still new here. Seriously, am I meant to repeat other people's points?

Answer (score 1):

This one is very easy.
IHOP - I have other plans

Comment: While this might be correct, it just repeats what has already been said in other answers with no explanation.

Comment: @ColleenV, sorry, but what is there to explain? He just asked what the meaning was and I answered.

Comment: See this discussion on meta - [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117/). If this were the only answer that said "I have other plans" was what IHOP meant, it might view it a little differently, but it doesn't add anything to what is already here. The last two paragraphs of Mike's answer is a good example of adding an explanation to a simple answer.